# How to auto-fill form with URL params in Symfony2

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.3, formbuilder

I have a view in Symfony 2.3 that shows a full list of employee likes and dislikes. I am trying to create a simple form at the top of this view to filter the list by employee by name.

I have currently created the form within a twig template using regular HTML and some TWIG conditional statements to check if the employee_name GET param matches one of the employees. This solution works but isn't ideal.

```
<form action="{{ path('report') }}" method="GET">
    <select id='employee_name' name='employee_name'>
         <option value='John' {% if app.request.get("employee_name") == 'John' %} selected {% endif %}>John</option>
         <option value='Aaron' {% if app.request.get("employee_name") == 'Aaron' %} selected {% endif %}>Aaron</option>
         <option value='Sam' {% if app.request.get("employee_name") == 'Sam' %} selected {% endif %}>Sam</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

My question is, is there a way to write the above form using the Form Builder and still have it auto-fill the fields when submitting? I'd like my filter form to be scalable and reusable. Perhaps it be would better to just use an Twig Include? Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. Just create the form with the form builder and render it in Twig. Since you're using the `GET` method and if you're calling `$form->handleRequest($request)`, the form will have the right values selected based on `GET` parameters.

Comment: When submitting the form with via FormBuilder and GET method, the URL receives all the fields within the form and they're being passed with the bracket naming convention which is being encoded. Any ideas? I'd like my url to read ?employee_name=Andrew

Example: http://localhost/app_dev.php/report/?form%5Bemployee_name%5D=Andrew&form%5Bsubmit%5D=&form%5B_token%5D=4b488fb0191e917c5ea0d2c2f5447d76721ad101